# Ошибка компиляции программы на С++ под FreeBSD

Tags: c++, freebsd, g++

Код:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string from_int(int number){
  stringstream ss;
  ss << number;
  return ss.str();
}
 int main(int argc, char** argv) {           
    string zz;
    zz=from_int(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка на FreeBSD 9:

```
root@nemesis:/home/gavnetadmin/tst # g++ -c -g main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.2/sstream:588: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token
```

На Ubuntu 15.10 компилируется без проблем. В чем я неправ?

Comment: у меня FreeBSD-9.3,  Ваш пример нормально компилится

Comment: Версия компилятора какая? `g++ -v`

Comment: версия 4.2.1-patched, правда если дописать вывод строки в консоль, скомпилить и запустить - ничего не выводит...

Comment: @margosh я вообще-то у ТС интересовался :) Но 4.2.1 это ж очень старая (July 18, 2007).

Comment: @alexolut, ну, будет для сравнения значит :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот она! Рыба моей мечты. Почти 2 дня мучений, чтоб подобрать состав ключей для компиляции!

```
g++ -o shaper main.cpp -lmysqlclient -I/usr/local/include/mysql -I/usr/local/include/ -L/usr/local/lib/mysql
```

Порядок включения библиотек в проект:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
```

Как в конечном итоге оказалось, порядок включения, тоже очень важен. В самом верху  iostream, затем обьявляем пространство имен std,  затем все остальные библиотеки. Причем те которые с расширением *.h рекомендуют опускать в самый низ. Причем под Ubuntu компилировалось всё без проблем сразу, и в любом порядке. А вот со FreeBSD ыли вот такие пляски с бубном.

Answer (score 1):

Вы должны включить заголовки

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

Объявления из заголовка `<fstream>` вообще не используются в вашей программе. Так что его следует убрать.

и по крайней мере использовать директиву

```
using namespace std;
```

В противном случае вам надо явно указывать префиксы стандартного пространства имен перед каждым именем из этого пространства.

Другая причина может состоять в том, что вам нужно установить опцию компилятора, которая указывает на поддержку C++ 2011.

Ошибка, похоже, связана с тем, что старый стандарт C++ не позволяет в определениях шаблонов ставить два знака >> рядом. Поэтому шаблонные конструкции могут интерпретироваться как ошибочные.

Comment: Не помогло.. Тож самое..

Comment: @PavelGribov Уберите заголовок fstream.

Comment: Не помогло, тож самое ((

Comment: @PavelGribov Не может быть тоже самое, так как предыдущее сообщение ссылается на fstream. Если возникло новое сообщение об ошибке, то приведите его полный текст.

Comment: Да на ssstream теперь ругается: In file included from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.2/sstream:588: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token

Comment: @PavelGribov Смотрите мое обновленное сообщение.

Comment: @PavelGribov Поместите заголовок iostream первым.

Comment: Да, сработало. Спасибо. Но легче не стало )) Сейчас в большом файле буду include тасовать чтоб откомпилировалось.. Не совсем понятно что в каком порядке нужно..

Comment: Никак не могу сделать чтоб ужились #include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <my_global.h>
#include <math.h>

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31859/discussion-between-pavel-gribov-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @PavelGribov Я не понял, причем здесь эти заголовки?!

Comment: Это уже из другой программы заголовки. Которые сейчас перетасовываю туда-сюда, чтоб откомпилировалось. Проблема такая-же: не уживаются вместе #include <fstream> и  #include <sstream>